# Lost passport at Heathrow while in transit from USA to India

Tags: airports, paperwork, indian-citizens, lhr

My sister-in-law and her husband along with their 5 yo are travelling from USA to India via London Heathrow. The husband lost his passport at Heathrow after getting off from the plane from USA to Heathrow and before boarding the flight to India. They got in writing from immigration that their passport at airport, however their connecting flight refused to board them without an emergency certificate which they will get from the Indian embassy. However, they don't have UK visas and therefore can't leave the airport.

What can they do?

Comment: They are Indian citizens?  Phone the Indian embassy and ask for advice.

Comment: Bollywood version of "The Terminal" starring Tom Khan...

Comment: Did they try asking at the UK Border? They might be able to get an emergency one day transit visa to get to the embassy. Otherwise, phoning the embassy seems like the best bet, it can't be the first time it has happened!

Comment: Also see [What happens if you lose your passport at an airport / during transit?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11701/108)