# Airline asking for power of attourney before paying compensation

Tags: passports, airlines, paperwork, compensation, iberia

My partner and I (both based in the UK) were delayed on a recent flight to Spain with Iberia airline.  After a lot of back and forth communication between my partner and Iberia, they have agreed to pay us compensation.

However, they have told us they need the following information from us, in order to pay us:

> In order for us to proceed with the payment, please send us the following bank details to e-mail cacgestionjuridica@iberia.es  :
>
> - Power of Attorney signed by all the passengers involved.
> - A copy of the clients’ passports
> - Bank details with the name and full address of the bank (street name and umber, post code and town/city)
> - Account holder’s complete name, VAT number and postal address.
> - Account number
> - IBAN and SWIFT codes

We are unclear as to what "power of attorney" means in this situation.  My partner thinks it is badly translated, and simply means that they want me to write and sign a letter saying she can claim the compensation on my behalf, but I'm not so sure.   I'm obviously not very happy giving actual legal power of attourney to an airline, nor does this request make any sense to me.

We are also concerned about sending scanned copies of our passports, [for the usual reasons](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-to-best-respond-to-a-request-to-send-a-passport-scan-by-unsecured-email).

Are these requests standard practice?  Should we be concerned?  Should we comply?  What exactly do they mean by "power of attourney" and what should we send them?

Comment: They're not asking for the passengers to give power of attorney to _the airline_. They're asking for each passenger to give power of attorney _to the person who will be receiving the compensation_. If they don't, what's to stop the passenger to approach the airline afterwards and keep wanting more, saying that they never authorized you to accept the airline's offer of compensation on their behalf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [official form](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/themes/passengers/air/doc/complain_form/eu_complaint_form_en.pdf) from the EU for compensation under Regulation (EC) 261/2004.

You do not have to provide any extraneous information not specifically requested by the standard EU form however the truth is they have to verify you are who you are claiming to be somehow and hence the request for ID/Passport.

I also believe the Power of Attorney in this case is as you describe because although she may have purchased the ticket, the compensation is to go to you and you need to authorize them to pay it to/through her.

Iberia is a legitimate airline and I would not have too much problem sending them scans of your passport. From my experience with United, the information they are requesting is pretty standard.