# Is a request for a passport number reasonable and safe?

Tags: passports, safety, security

I'm staying in an Airbnb in the Dominican Republic and the host--an Airbnb Superhost, with many good reviews--has asked the following:

> Please make sure to send me the full names and passport or ID numbers of all the people coming to the Villa. That way I can issue an invitation for you and you will have a smooth registration process at the entrance of the resort. Security is really high so nobody without any sort of access pass can get into the resort. Plus, with this invitation, you will not have to pay any resort fee, which is 20$/person/day.

This sounds reasonable to me, but I am wondering if there could be any scam here or other risk to me by providing this information. Does this kind of invitation sound normal? Can any harm come of someone knowing your passport number?

Comment: Most hotels by default take copies of our passports & credit cards and we know hotel databases are routinely hacked and information stolen. If I can trust a hotel chain with my passport **and credit card data**, I can trust an Airbnb superhost with my passport data. But that’s just me. We just have to accept nothing is 100% safe. It’s a matter of personal risk tolerance vs odds of something bad happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most hotels by default take copies of our passports & credit cards and we know hotel databases are routinely hacked and information stolen.

If I can trust a hotel chain with my passport **and credit card data**, I can trust an Airbnb superhost with my passport data. But that’s just me. We just have to accept nothing is 100% safe. It’s a matter of personal risk tolerance vs odds of something bad happening.

> Does this kind of invitation sound normal? Can any harm come of
>   someone knowing your passport number?

It’s not unheard of. I have twice (maybe three times) provided my passport info to Airbnb hosts in Spain and Brazil. Experts say someone having only your passport number can do relatively little damage without access to other info.

**SOURCES**

[How to best respond to a request to send a passport scan by unsecured email?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-to-best-respond-to-a-request-to-send-a-passport-scan-by-unsecured-email?rq=1)

[Marriott reveals data breach of 500 million Starwood guests](https://www.cnn.com/2018/11/30/tech/marriott-hotels-hacked/index.html)

> Marriott says its guest reservation system has been hacked,
>   potentially exposing the personal information of approximately 500
>   million guests.
>
> The hotel chain said Friday the hack affects its Starwood reservation
>   database, a group of hotels it bought in 2016 that includes the St.
>   Regis, Westin, Sheraton and W Hotels.