# is it safe to share a scanned copy of my international passport to the any recruiting agency?

Tags: international-travel

i want to work in singapore/canada for sometime and the local recruiting consultancies are asking me to share my passport details for onward process. it is heard that this kind is dangerous. what do you say?

Comment: Personally, I would ask them what they need it for.

Comment: Also relevant https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-to-best-respond-to-a-request-to-send-a-passport-scan-by-unsecured-email/39084#39084