# Vietnam visa application online safety

Tags: visas, passports, paperwork, security, vietnam

There are several websites which offer to get Vietnam visa by applying online, they require sending passport and other personal data. How to know that selected website for visa issuing is reliable and secure? Is there any list of government approved? Which is the most common option?

Related discussion: [Has Anyone Used https://vietnamvisa.govt.vn](https://www.tripadvisor.ie/ShowTopic-g293921-i8432-k8708472-Has_Anyone_Used_https_vietnamvisa_govt_vn-Vietnam.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to best respond to a request to send a passport scan by unsecured email?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-to-best-respond-to-a-request-to-send-a-passport-scan-by-unsecured-email)

Comment: Question bit different. Communication channel can be secure but the company may be not reliable - anyone can create website which issues visas.

Comment: Probably the only truly secure method is to apply direct (eg in person, post, by email) at a the appropriate Vietnamese embassy for your country of residence.

Comment: Can you get a visa on arrival instead?

Comment: Visa on arrival still requires an invitation letter/application ahead of time which involves forking over passport details. Or at least, it did when I did it two years ago; perhaps it's different for other nationalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to contribute for the above answer for some:
Actually, there are many websites that offer Vietnam visa services like https://www.vietnam-visa.com/, [https://vietnamvisa.govt.vn](https://vietnamvisa.govt.vn/), https://www.vietnam-evisa.org/, and many more.
They are all approved by the Vietnam government to process visa service. However, it's worth noting that the one with "govt.vn" is not of Vietnam's government. It is just .govt, not .gov. Many people are often confused by this website, so be careful if you are also.

In fact, they are just service providers working under the visa service. About reliability, it can be said that they are relatively reliable, but the quality of service of each provider will be varied.
Normally, if you don't mind to go to Vietnam embassy / consulate in your local, then you can choose to apply for Vietnam visa at the embassy, but if you are not familiar with the procedures of applying and getting visa, you can consider using these providers. They will work to help you fasten and simplify the process of getting visa. It also does not cost much when you use visa on arrival or e-visa (even cheaper in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any list of government approved? Which is the most common option?

This is the official eVisa website for Vietnam: **evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn**

> Outside Vietnam foreigners who want to enter Vietnam can [personally apply for E-visa](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/en_US/web/guest/khai-thi-thuc-dien-tu/cap-thi-thuc-dien-tu) or through the inviting/guaranteeing agencies and organizations.

Source: [National Web Portal on Immigration](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/trang-chu-ttdt)

All other sites on different domains may well be legitimate but are not affiliate with government and they clearly disclaim that fact.

**I would always apply on the website run by the government**, even when that is not the only option.