# How do I protect my I-94 travel history?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, i-94

I need help in hiding my i94 travel history so anyone with my passport number can track my whereabouts. Could someone please let me know how?

Comment: I don't think you can, though: 1. they also need your birth date (and full name), 2. they would be committing fraud (perjury) if they access your data without your consent, 3. they can only find out when you enter or exit the US (and through which airport), not the details of where you are.

Comment: Even if the answer is "it's not possible," this is a great question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87973/discussion-on-question-by-gita-g-how-do-i-protect-my-i-94-travel-history).

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way** to protect your I-94 history against someone who has your passport details, so your only way of securing your data is to protect your passport from being accessible to third parties. If you're a dual citizen, you could for example show one passport to US immigration and show a second passport to everyone else. Otherwise you should simply be vigilant about data protection.

Likewise nothing prevents others from applying for an ESTA or other electronic visa on your behalf, which could have much more serious consequences for you in the future than a mere loss of privacy. See further discussion of potential harm from personal data theft on our [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/what-harm-can-be-done-with-a-copy-of-ones-passport).