# Greek hotels taking pictures of passports for tourist tax

Tags: paperwork, hotels, greece, photography

Has anyone had the experience of having their passport photographed at check-in at Greek hotels? This has happened to me twice at different hotels. I travel often to Greece and this practice was never done before. Apparently, this is done for the purpose of paying the "tourist tax". I have nothing against the tax, but leaving a picture of my travel document in some clerk's phone is a gross infringement of privacy and has tremendous potential for misuse.

Does anyone have any advice on how legal this is in Greece and what to do about it?

Comment: Related: [What harm can be done with a copy of one's passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/what-harm-can-be-done-with-a-copy-of-ones-passport)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139019/discussion-on-question-by-veljko-greek-hotels-taking-pictures-of-passports-for-t).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen in many countries.

According to [Travel and Leisure](https://www.travelandleisure.com/hotels-resorts/why-do-european-hotels-require-passports-at-check-in):

> This procedure isn’t meant to inconvenience anyone. Quite the contrary. These hotels keep a record of passports to cross check for wanted criminals, look for missing persons, or protect against identity thieves.

According to [Mashable](https://mashable.com/article/hotel-passport-data-collection):

> Mostly, it's not actually the fault of hotels. The decision to both
> collect and store ID information including passports originates with
> the government in whatever location a hotel is.
>
> "That idea of a hotel as a place you can go and be anonymous isn’t
> universally true," Katie Moussouris, security expert and CEO of
> LutaSecurity, a company that helps governments design bug bounties,
> said. "A lot of the motivation behind it is for law enforcement
> purposes."

Comment: Please avoid copying text from other sites without adding references. I've updated your answer to our preferred format.

Comment: I've got no problem with the general purpose of it. But I do have a big problem with sending high-resolution scans of my passport to virtual landlords, or having a picture taken of my documents from a receptionist on private phones (and generally any device that can resend that picture to a milion people). I see limitless misuse opportunities here. If you can't fanthom at least one, then you're a very naive person. It's not a surprise that in most countries processing and storing of pictures of ID documents is a highly regulated area, allowed to government institutions and banks only.