# Lost passport visa and citizen card in Malaysia

Tags: visas, passports, malaysia, identity-cards

My Nepalese friend has lost his passport, visa, and his citizen card in Malaysia. His flight is in a week, and if he goes to police, they want his permit card, and he doesn't have it. What should he do in this situation?

Comment: What nationality is he? What kind of visa does he have for Malaysia?

Comment: nepal . and i am nt sure about his visa

Comment: He is Nepalese?

Comment: yes he is nepalese

Comment: The passport side of the question is already covered in [this earlier question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/what-to-do-if-i-lost-my-passport-before-flight-in-another-country?rq=1). It would be nice if someone could provide some info on how to avoid problems with Malaysian authorities or even get the visa reissued if that's possible at all.

Answer (score 18):

In general, when a traveller loses their passport they should contact a consulate or embassy of the country where they are a citizen. The consulate may be able to quickly issue an emergency passport or other travel document, that will allow the holder to travel and depart the country they are in. However, the traveller should definitely seek to replace their passport as soon as possible, as international travel is difficult without one.

Since your friend is from Nepal, he should contact the [Embassy of Nepal in Kuala Lumpur](http://www.nepalembassy.com.my/en/). There is a page for [Loss of passport](http://www.nepalembassy.com.my/en/services_passport_loss.html) which states:

> 1. Nepali nationals who are visiting Malaysia/Indonesia/Philippines on a tourist visa may contact the embassy in case of loss of passport with police report, and a attested copy of the lost passport or attested copy of Nepali citizenship certificate along with the proof of purpose of the visit to the respective countries.
> 2. Upon review, the embassy may issue passport or travel document.

Comment: I'm curious, are you expected to carry attested copies of your passport with you when traveling?

Comment: @Akash Not necessarily but any document you can provide can help when dealing with your consulate. Even having a driver's license can be useful.

Comment: Its worth highlighting that the police report is very important; without this you can have 20 attested copies but nothing can be done.